# Set cart total in round format in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to set Order total in round format in cart page in woocommerce. How can I do it?
e.g. one of my product has price $699.
there is discount of 8% in this product, so its price becomes $643.08

So, in cart it show $643.08, but I want to set this total as $643.10.
and total should go as final total in payment method and all other places. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Use php round function http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Yes, I can use echo round( 1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
but where i need to add this in woocommerce, in which file? so it can affect everywhere in site ?

Comment: You have to apply this where you will get $643.08 this value